# Solving system of linear equations with cyclic three-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

I have this problem in my textbook:

> Suggest efficient algorithm for solving system of linear equations with cyclic three-diagonal matrix, that is of the form:
>    \begin{bmatrix} a_1&b_1&0&\cdots&0&d_1\\c_2&a_2&b_2&0&\vdots&0\\0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0&\vdots\\\vdots&\vdots&c_{n-2}&a_{n-2}&b_{n-2}&0\\0&\cdots&\cdots&c_{n-1}&a_{n-1}&b_{n-1}\\d_2&0&\cdots&0&c_n&a_n\end{bmatrix}
>   without swapping any rows and columns. Estimate complexity.

And I don't know how to approach this. Classic elimination would work in very efficient $O(n)$ time with this matrix, but the problem is when, let's say, I want to eliminate $c_{2}$ with $1$-st row that is add to second row $\frac{-c_{2}}{a_{1}}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_1&b_1&0&\cdots&0&d_1 \end{bmatrix}$ and when $a_1=0$. I can't do that, and even if $a_1\neq 0$ then the same problem can occur somewhere in the middle of this proccess. Moreover, as the problem text states, I am not allowed to swap any rows or columns, so I don't know if this approach can be somehow fixed. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have the answer at
http://nikolavitas.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/three-diagonal-periodic-system-of.html

The algorithm is still very efficient as it uses 2 times Gaussian elimination at n-1 x n-1 matrix.

I coded the method in IDL. You won't have much trouble to translate it to any other language.